# HTML5 formatter/pretty printer for vim?

Tags: vim

What's the best way get text formatting/pretty printing for HTML5 in Vim?

I just tried HTML Tidy (from Ubuntu 12.04 repo) and by default it seems to not recognize HTML5 tags like Header, Footer, Article, Section, and tries to throw them out.  I don't see an obvious switch or config setting to fix this.

Is there a better option?  I'd be happy with just being able to batch fix indentations, anything beyond that is gravy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at installing a syntax file or plugin for Vim geared towards HTML5. Such as [this by othree](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim). Afterwards you should be able to `gg=G` to format your HTML.

While we're on the topic, you may want to install [emmet.vim](http://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/) a handy dandy zencoding like plugin for Vim which will make writing any HTML much quicker.